# GoogleMap Cannot be resolved to a type, Android api v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am able to display a map and update my location. However I added this button to take a screenshot of the current map. I believe I have all the proper imports and the google play library because the map is displaying properly. Eclipse tells me in this:

```
new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback()




"GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback cannot be resolved to a type"
```

Here is the code.

```
 Button screen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    screen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ScreenShot in sdcard",
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                public void onMapLoaded() {
                    mMap.snapshot(new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                        public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap bitmap) {
                            // Write image to disk
                            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/map.png");
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

What do I need to do to make this resolve to a type and what does that mean?

Comment: @gaurav5430 Could this be a recent addition to the google play services jar file? Because I can't find the OnMapLoadedCallback there to interface it.

Answer (score 0):

An update to the Google Play services Library was released November 2013 (Google Play services 4.0.30). The previous library did not include the OnMapLoadedCallback interface.

Instructions for installation of the update for incorporation into your android project can be found at

```
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html
```